# who i can link html page to MS-access database?

Tags: html, database, ms-access

Hi every one  i need to link a html page to an access database and it will help if anyone can gave me the html code for searching that database thanks .
i work with access 2010

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you'll have to save the page as a file to a local or network drive of yours. Then link an HTML table of the file.

This is what *Excel* does behind the scene when you attach a URL.